# How to get previous value using LAG in Oracle but is not included in retrieved data?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi this my example here:

```
SELECT empno,
       ename,
       job,
       sal,
       LAG(sal, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY sal) AS sal_prev,
       sal - LAG(sal, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY sal) AS sal_diff
FROM   emp;
```

and here the output:

```
 EMPNO| ENAME| JOB           |  SAL  | SAL_PREV   | SAL_DIFF
 -----|------|-----------------------------------------------
  1000| SMITH| CLERK         |   800 |         0  |      800
  1001| JAMES| CLERK         |   950 |       800  |      150
  1002| ADAMS| CLERK         |  1100 |       950  |      150
  1003| WARD | SALESMAN      |  1250 |      1100  |      150
```

I know the lag is only applied within the rows that match the where clause filter but if i add `where EMPNO > 1001` i can't get the previous value, is there a proper way to retrieve previous value that is not included in off data?

I use Oracle 12c.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. What should the output look like? Why would you add `where EMPNO > 1001` - what is the requirement you are trying to implement, and why is your current code not a good solution? What is wrong with it?

Comment: @mathguy the where is just example to try to filer the data in the table i just want some data that range between two dates (in reality) and if i did this my SAL_PREV for 1002 it will be 0 but it's wrong i need it to be 950.

Comment: Oh, understood. I assume the dates cannot be equal (unlike the SAL in your example, where they may be equal); and you are not excluding employee 1000, you are excluding the employee with the highest salary. Take a look at Gordon's solution, which does pretty much what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT empno, ename, job, sal,
             LAG(sal, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY sal) AS sal_prev,
             (sal - LAG(sal, 1, 0) OVER (empno ORDER BY sal)) AS sal_diff
      FROM  emp
     ) e
WHERE empno > 1001;
```

Comment: But this will try searching for all data in the table then it will filter it, i did think of your solution but this query will so mush longer to execute. i give you just an example in my real production the table is big and the query is complex.

Comment: @IsmailSensei - you can have a WHERE clause in the subquery (to limit the date range - but make sure it includes the row you need to reject later), and another WHERE clause in the outer query. Note also that LAG(sal) would work here - you don't care about LAG(sal, 1, 0) since the only row affected by ...1, 0 is the row that you are discarding in the outer query anyway.

Comment: @IsmailSensei Note also that if your filter in the outer query is the same as the partition by of the LAG function in the subquery, Oracle can and will push the outer predicate into the inner query. In your example query, Oracle won't be able to do that, since you're finding the previous salary across the whole set of data, so that has to be calculated first before you can filter on the empno. You may (assuming the appropriate indexes are in place) benefit from using something like `select ..., (select max(sal) from emp e2 where e2.sal < e1.sal) prev_sal from emp e1 where empno = 1001`